# Use specific version of atoms language package

Tags: syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

It seems like the `language-javascript` Atom package has been updated and I really do not like it. Thus I have tried to install an older one like this:

```
apm install language-javascript@0.129.10
```

Which gave me following feedback:

```
The language-javascript package is bundled with Atom and should not be
explicitly installed.
You can run `apm uninstall language-javascript` to uninstall it and then the 
version bundled with Atom will be used.
```

Now Im stuck. I dont want use the version bundled with Atom, rather an older one (that used to be bundled with Atom).

The suggested `apm uninstall language-javascript` command does not work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to achieve that:

#### Use `apm develop`

This is the [recommended way](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-can-i-edit-core-packages/23016) by the developers of Atom. From the `apm` help:

> Clone the given package's Git repository to the directory specified,
>   install its dependencies, and link it for development to
>   `~/.atom/dev/packages/<package_name>`.
>
> If no directory is specified then the repository is cloned to
>   `~/github/<package_name>.`

The major drawback is that this only work in Developer Mode (`atom --dev`), which is probably not what you want.

#### Fork the package

I haven't tested this, but from my understanding of Atom it should work:

1. Disable the bundled `language-javascript` package
2. Clone your preferred version to `~/.atom/packages` using a unique name
3. Put the unique name to the `name` key of the package's manifest (`package.json`)
4. Restart Atom and enable the package

**Example:**

```
# Let's use the versions commit as name
git clone https://github.com/atom/language-javascript --branch v0.129.10 language-javascript-fd5835e
```

Comment: On opening Atom I got promted with: `Failed to load a jsok package grammar`. Referencing to `grammars/tree-sitter-javascript.cson` and `grammars/tree-sitter-regex.cson`, the two dependencies of the main package. It says thoes two modules couldnt be found even though they are right there.

Answer (score 0):

Start Atom and under the Atom menu select Preferences. This opens a settings pane and on the left is a list of features you can set on Atom. The list starts with Core and includes Editor, URI Handling and other options. Near the bottom is Install. Click on Install and this gives you access to all extensions. Look for the extension you want and it will be shown in the window on the right. There will be buttons to install or uninstall the extension. You should be able to uninstall the new version and then look for older version and install it.